# Rhino Mock Entity Framework using UnitofWork Pattern not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit, rhino-mocks

This is my first attempt at something like this, so hopefully this is simple.

I have created a WCF service which uses Entity Framework to access the database. I have implemented a *UnitOfWork* interface so my service can use EF while still being testable.

Here is my service:

```
public class ProjectService : IProjectService
{
    private IUnitOfWork db = null;

    public ProjectService(IUnitOfWork unitofwork)
    {
        db = unitofwork;
    }

    public int RegisterSite(int CPUID)
    {
        if (db.Servers.Count(x => x.CPUID == CPUID) > 0)
        {
            // do something
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my UnitOfWork interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IObjectSet<tblClient> Clients { get; }
    IObjectSet<tblServer> Servers { get; }
    IObjectSet<tblSite> Sites { get; }
    IObjectSet<tblServerLog> ServerLogs { get; }
    void Commit();
}
```

When I use this Service with either concrete implementations of a `SQLUnitOfWork` (using EF) or with a `InMemoryUnitOfWork` (just in memory objects) then it works fine.

After testing fine with my in memory objects i tried this test.

```
[Test]
public void RegisterAnExistingServer()
    {
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();

        IUnitOfWork MockUnitOfWork = mocks.DynamicMock<IUnitOfWork>();

        ProjectService service = new ProjectService(MockUnitOfWork);


        Expect.Call(MockUnitOfWork.Servers.Count(x => x.CPUID == 1234)).Return(0);

        mocks.ReplayAll();

        int NewSiteID = service.RegisterSite(1234);

        mocks.VerifyAll();
    }
```

But when I try using it in Rhino Mock with an Expectation on Servers.Count I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: arguments
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, String paramName)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ref ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Perhaps the error refers to that `Servers` is null. I think you have to set that up too.

Comment: so i added this line 
`MockUnitOfWork.Servers = mocks.StrictMock<IObjectSet<tblServer>>();` and still the same error. Is that what you meant?

Comment: One suggestion, I would not use the Record and Playback syntax as it has been superceeded by the preferred Arrange-Act-Assert style. With RhinoMocks it can be hard to tell them apart due to the API being in the same namespace (last time I checked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MikeEast is correct.  Rhino.Mocks doesn't do recursive mocking.  You need to mock up the Servers property to return something (just create an empty IObjectSet<tblServer> and set that up as the return value).

Also, you don't want to set expectations on lambdas.  Once everything gets compiled, the lambda in your code and the lambda in your unit test are two totally different methods (and your expectation will always fail).  See http://groups.google.com/group/rhinomocks/msg/318a35ae7536d90a for more details.

Answer (score -6):

There is probably some reflection going on internally and hence you are not getting a straight forward call to your unit of work.

I strongly suggest switching to nhibernate. Also, ditch WCF.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Also WCF and EF are the frameworks we are using can't just switch.

Comment: Just because you dont know the answer doenst mean that the frameworks he is using are bad and he should switch! How are you allowed to have this reputation with answers like this one?

Comment: I have this reputation because people vote for my answers. Compare nhibernate (1st and 2nd level cache, extension points, multiple databases, etc) with EF and you will see. Then take a look at something like ServiceStack (in code setup, easy forward maintenance) and compare it to WCF. The question was "what am I doing wrong". So suggesting NH and SS are applicable.