# Unit Test Value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I am trying to unit test this code,

```
public bool IsCityAvailable(Appointment appointment)
{
    var city = _customerRepository.Find(appointment.CustomerId).City;
    return _employeeRepository.Get.Count(x => x.City == city) > 0;
 }
```

Here is my test,

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        MockAppointmentRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Appointment>>();
        MockCustomerRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Customer>>();
        MockShiftRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Shift>>();
        MockEmployeeRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Employee>>();

        AppointmentService = new AppointmentService(MockCustomerRepository.Object, MockAppointmentRepository.Object, MockShiftRepository.Object, MockEmployeeRepository.Object);

        Customer = new Customer()
        {
            Address = "88 Taraview Road NE",
            City = "Calgary",
            Email = "charles.norris@outlook.com",
            FirstName = "Charles",
            LastName = "Norris",
            Id = 1,
            Phone = "587-888-8882",
            PostalCode = "X1X 1X1",
            Province = "AB"
        };

        Employee1 = new Employee()
        {
            Address = "12 Saddletowne Road NW",
            City = "Calgary",
            Email = "johnny.bravo@outlook.com",
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Bravo",
            Id = 2,
            Phone = "403-999-2222",
            PostalCode = "X1X 1X1",
            Province = "AB"
        };

        Employee2 = new Employee()
        {
            Address = "12 Saddletowne Road NW",
            City = "Calgary",
            Email = "johnny.bravo@outlook.com",
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Bravo",
            Id = 2,
            Phone = "403-999-2222",
            PostalCode = "X1X 1X1",
            Province = "AB"
        };

        Appointment = new Appointment()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Customer = Customer,
            CustomerId = Customer.Id,
            Employee = Employee1,
            EmployeeId = Employee1.Id,
            ScheduledTime = new DateTime(2013,10,15,18,30,00)
        };
    }

[Test]
public void IsCityAvailableShouldReturnAvailableWhenEmployeeInSameCityFound()
{
    // ARRANGE
    var employees = new List<Employee> { Employee1, Employee2 };

    var result = new Mock<IQueryable<Employee>>();
    result.Setup(r => r.GetEnumerator()).Returns(employees.GetEnumerator());

    MockCustomerRepository.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Customer);
    MockEmployeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Get).Returns(result.Object);

    // ACT
    AppointmentService.IsCityAvailable(Appointment);

    // ASSERT
    MockCustomerRepository.Verify(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
    MockEmployeeRepository.Verify(x => x.Get, Times.Once);
}
```

I have debugged and stepped through can't find the value null it is referring to, my city variable is correct, the appointment parameter is fully populated. Is there something missing I am not seeing?

This is the output error from the unit test:

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   arguments

Here is the stacktrace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: arguments
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ref ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Zenwire.Services.AppointmentService.IsCityAvailable(Appointment appointment) in AppointmentService.cs: line 81
   at Tests.Unit.Zenwire.Services.AppointmentServiceTests.IsCityAvailableShouldReturnAvailableWhenEmployeeInSameCityFound() in AppointmentServiceTests.cs: line 100
```

Comment: is `_employeeRepository` null? Something will be null. You just need to look harder. Realistically, we could all guess for you but without being able to debug the code it could be anything.

Comment: looks like // ACT
    AppointmentService.IsCityAvailable(Appointment);
"Appointment" is null

Comment: When I step through it, appointment is populated. I think the issue is with the mock setup?

Comment: See if this link is any helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335661/rhino-mock-entity-framework-using-unitofwork-pattern-not-working

Comment: The problem is that you not returning any objects from your _employeeRepository. And when you are trying to make a count on an list with no elements the x.City returns null. 

Solution; MockEmployeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Get).Returns(new List<Employee> { Employee1, Employee2 }).AsQueryable();

Comment: One thing to note is that while your actual method looks pretty clean, you're violating the "Principle of Least Knowledge" or "Law of Demeter". Some people also call this walking the dots, and generally, you want to avoid doing this. The "Principle of Least Knowledge" says talk to your immediate friends only. In your first line of application code, you call: `_customerRepository.Find(appointment.CustomerId).City` There may not be a better way, but this means you have to wire up a few things just to make that line of code work. That can make it difficult to test and maintain over time.

Comment: The approach you took may make the most sense in this scenario.The alternative here would be to pass the customer into the method, which your calling code may never need access to. So, it may be as clean as you can make it already, it's more of a heads up for the future, because this can lead to really difficult test scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test that everyhing has been called correctly:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    MockAppointmentRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Appointment>>();
    MockCustomerRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Customer>>();
    MockShiftRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Shift>>();
    MockEmployeeRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Employee>>();

    AppointmentService = new AppointmentService(MockCustomerRepository.Object, MockAppointmentRepository.Object, MockShiftRepository.Object, MockEmployeeRepository.Object);

    Customer = new Customer()
    {
        Address = "88 Taraview Road NE",
        City = "Calgary",
        Email = "charles.norris@outlook.com",
        FirstName = "Charles",
        LastName = "Norris",
        Id = 1,
        Phone = "587-888-8882",
        PostalCode = "X1X 1X1",
        Province = "AB"
    };

    Employee1 = new Employee()
    {
        Address = "12 Saddletowne Road NW",
        City = "Calgary",
        Email = "johnny.bravo@outlook.com",
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Bravo",
        Id = 2,
        Phone = "403-999-2222",
        PostalCode = "X1X 1X1",
        Province = "AB"
    };

    Employee2 = new Employee()
    {
        Address = "12 Saddletowne Road NW",
        City = "Calgary",
        Email = "johnny.bravo@outlook.com",
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Bravo",
        Id = 2,
        Phone = "403-999-2222",
        PostalCode = "X1X 1X1",
        Province = "AB"
    };

    Appointment = new Appointment()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Customer = Customer,
        CustomerId = Customer.Id,
        Employee = Employee1,
        EmployeeId = Employee1.Id,
        ScheduledTime = new DateTime(2013,10,15,18,30,00)
    };
}

[Test]
public void IsCityAvailableShouldReturnAvailableWhenEmployeeInSameCityFound()
{
// ARRANGE
MockCustomerRepository.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Customer);
MockEmployeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Get).Returns(new List<Employee> { Employee1, Employee2 }.AsQueryable());

// ACT
AppointmentService.IsCityAvailable(Appointment);

// ASSERT
MockCustomerRepository.Verify(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
MockEmployeeRepository.Verify(x => x.Get, Times.Once);
}
```

Test the return value:

```
[Test]
public void IsCityAvailableShouldReturnAvailableWhenEmployeeInSameCityFound()
{
// ARRANGE
MockCustomerRepository.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Customer);
MockEmployeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Get).Returns(new List<Employee> { Employee1, Employee2 }.AsQueryable());

// ACT
var actual = AppointmentService.IsCityAvailable(Appointment);

// ASSERT
Assert.IsTrue(actual);
}
```