# Unit Testing IQueryable operations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore, sitecore7

While writing a unit test for a Sitecore 7 search class, following the pattern established here (https://github.com/Sitecore/sitecore-seven-unittest-example/blob/master/ExampleFixture.cs), I am running into an issue where in order to make my tests pass I need to add `AsEnumerable()` to the Sitecore LINQ expression.

Here is my unit test:

```
[Test]
public void Provider_WhenCalled_MatchesPath()
{
  //arrange
  var index = MakeSubstituteIndex(new List<EventPageSearchItem>
  {
   new EventPageSearchItem(){Path = "/good/path/folder1/item1", TemplateId = _eventTemplateId },
   new EventPageSearchItem{Path="/good/path/folder2/item2", TemplateId = _eventTemplateId},
   new EventPageSearchItem{Path="/bad/path/folder2/item2", TemplateId = _eventTemplateId}
            });
  //act
  var provider = new UpcomingEventProvider(index);
  var events = provider.GetEvents(3, "/good/path");

  //assert
  Assert.That(events.ToList(), Has.Count.EqualTo(2));
}

private static ISearchIndex MakeSubstituteIndex(List<EventPageSearchItem> itemsToReturn)
    {
        ISearchIndex index = Substitute.For<ISearchIndex>();
        _eventTemplateId = MyProject.Library.IEvent_PageConstants.TemplateId;

        SimpleFakeRepo<EventPageSearchItem> repo = new SimpleFakeRepo<EventPageSearchItem>(itemsToReturn);
        index.CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<EventPageSearchItem>().Returns(repo);
        return index;
    }


public class SimpleFakeRepo<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>
{
    public SimpleFakeRepo(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    {}
}
```

And this is my logic under test:

```
public class EventPageSearchItem: SearchResultItem
{
}

public interface IUpcomingEventProvider
{
    IEnumerable<EventPageSearchItem> GetEvents(int numberOfEvents, string rootItemPath);
}

public class UpcomingEventProvider : IUpcomingEventProvider
{
    private readonly ISearchIndex _searchIndex;

    public UpcomingEventProvider(ISearchIndex searchIndex)
    {
        _searchIndex = searchIndex;
    }

    public IEnumerable<EventPageSearchItem> GetEvents(int numberOfEvents, string rootItemPath)
    {
        var ctx = _searchIndex.CreateSearchContext();
        var queryable = ctx.GetQueryable<EventPageSearchItem>();
        return queryable
            .Where(item => 
                item.TemplateId== MyProject.Library.IEvent_PageConstants.TemplateId 
                && item.Path.StartsWith(rootItemPath)).Take(numberOfEvents);
    }
}
}
```

This is failing with this stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: arguments
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at MyProject.UnitTests.ComponentUtilityTests.UpcomingEventProvider.GetEvents(Int32 numberOfEvents, String rootItemPath)  
   at MyProject.UnitTests.ComponentUtilityTests.UpcomingEventProviderTests.    System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
```

If I modify the Linq expression to include AsEnumerable(), everything passes, but this will prevent the Linq from generating an expression tree for the index provider.

```
return queryable.AsEnumerable().Where( etc. )
```

Comment: I question whether you should unit test this at all. Did you design the classes returned by `CreateSearchContext` or `GetQueryable<EventPageSearchItem>`? If not, they're third party, and you don't need design feedback on them from your unit tests. I highly recommend giving [Why You Don't Get Mock Objects by Gregory Moeck](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9FOchgTtLM) a good listen. In a few months, watch it again. It made me start asking the question, "What are my tests really buying me?" I was surprised by the answers I came up with.

Comment: @jpm26 A very reasonable point. My real aim was to try to exercise the testability features of Sitecore 7, and especially the demo test project I linked to above, but I agree this looks like an antipattern (attempting to replicate 3rd party behavior inside a unit test)>

Comment: For what it's worth, this is NOT the right way to select an item in a path using Sitecore 7.  The Paths collection contains the IDs of all ancestors and the current item, so checking for all items that have the desired ancestor in Paths is much less error prone.  Code and learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the differences between your mocking frameworks, but I notice that Stephen's code explicitly sets up a fake return value for index.CreateSearchContext().  Your code does not as far as I can see.  That is the only notable difference I can see between your code and his.

A similar error message here also indicates that this error message can come from a lack of recursive mock support: [Rhino Mock Entity Framework using UnitofWork Pattern not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335661/rhino-mock-entity-framework-using-unitofwork-pattern-not-working)

Comment: +1 for reviewing and finding a difference from the model code.  I will unearth this commit and confirm whether this was the issue this weekend.